# date of app purchase date in Swift, start or end date

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I use the feature of purchase for weekly and monthly application.
Each time the user opens the app, check his or her purchase, if he/she have purchased, how can get both the subscription start and end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiko! You should validate your App Store receipt and get subscription info from there.

Here is basic example of validating receipt:

```swift
func validateReceipt(){

        #if DEBUG
                   let urlString = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
               #else 
                   let urlString = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
               #endif

        guard let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL, let receiptString = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptURL).base64EncodedString() , let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                return
        }

        let requestData : [String : Any] = ["receipt-data" : receiptString, 
                                            "password" : "YOUR_SHARED_SECRET", 
                                            "exclude-old-transactions" : false]
        let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestData, options: [])

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = httpBody
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)  { (data, response, error) in
            // convert data to Dictionary and view purchases
        }.resume()        
    }
```

After you validated a receipt, you should convert `data` to `Dictionary` and get expiration date in `latest_receipt_info`

You can use our [Apphud SDK](https://apphud.com) to track subscriptions info, including start and end date.

Also you can use [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) library, you can get subscription info there as well.

If you want to do this manually, then here is good article in our blog: https://blog.apphud.com/swift-tutorial-subscriptions/

Comment: adamın dibisin senin daşşanı yesinler

Comment: hi, what's YOUR_SHARED_SECRET